# QueryDSL: generate "S" classes from JPA entities

Tags: querydsl

QueryDSL looks pretty good, but is there a way to generate the "S" classes for SQL querying from an existent JPA model ?

I see that you can use com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor to generate the "Q" classes, and that you have to connect to a database to generate the "S" classes. But as all the metadata informations (tables, columns) can be found in the JPA entities, this should be sufficient to generate the "S" classes, isn't it ?

The purpose of this : not relying on a database schema that is, well, not reliable... and use QueryDSL on a side project where JPA won't be available.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need the S classes?

Comment: What I currently have: a JPA project in Java (J2EE, application server, blah blah...), and some scala jobs in Spark. 
I'd like to make some really small requests in SQL within the spark jobs, hence I don't want to take a JPA implementation within it. I don't think I can use querydsl-sql over the "Q" classes. But this "Q" classes, in the Java project, should be considered as a referential. So it would be great to generate the "S" classes from either the JPA model, or the Q classes.

Comment: I see. No that does not work because it's not intended for this use case. Why do you have "not reliable" database schema?

Comment: OK, I see. The thing is that's an on-going project with a lot of modifications (and the JPA project is the one leading the modifications of the schema). And that I'd like to avoid to put passwords in the pom.xml just to create the model. 
But I guess I'll just do it that way, and remove the password before committing.

Comment: You should also have a look at https://www.jooq.org/

Answer (score 0):

According to Simon (thanks by the way), it's not possible to do that. I'll stick with the traditionnal way of reverse-engineering the schema (and, who knows, if I have some free time, I'll try to implement the S classes generation from the jpa model).